# How do I draw tile in a side-on perspective?

Tags: 2d, tiles, perspective

All the tutorials I've found regarding using tiles in game engines refer to games with an isometric or top-down view, much like this:

[image: top-down]

I want to make a "beat em up"-game, where the view is tilted.

Examples include *Streets of Rage*, *Golden Axe*, *Knights of the Round* and *Castle Crashers*. They look much like this:

[image: side-on]

How do I draw a tile compatible with that view?

I'm using Photoshop and Inkscape.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Anko For example, try drawing a tileset (9 boxes) of ground soil and grass with an angle of 45 º positions but I can not fit ever. 
Do you know of any tutorial to learn how to design tilesets 45 degrees? Or show me an example of inclined tilemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The illusion of the camera being on the side comes from the background and characters being drawn from a side-on view. There are no special perspective tricks going on.

Let's have a closer look at that *Knights of the Round* screenshot.

First, I copied a region from the bottom left and moved it toward the right until I noticed that the grass at the bottom matched up:

[image: bottom grass tiling]

Observe the grass at the bottom. It appears not to change, because it's the same grass tile repeated at that point.

Clearly, the ground doesn't tile here though... Let's move that cutout region a little further:

[image: ground tiling]

Sure enough, the ground is made of repeating rectangular sprites too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One last thing, can you recommend some tool to design or perhaps a web page?

Comment: @ep If you're looking for a free tool, [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is my favourite for drawing tiles, but I know many developers prefer [Aseprite](http://www.aseprite.org/) because it has a smoother learning curve. You can easily adapt most tutorials (e.g. [the ones at OpenGameArt](http://opengameart.org/content/chapter-8-a-world-of-tiles)) to them. Studying existing games' art is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really that hard.
It is mostly the same but you just apply some foreshortening on the ground layer (e.g. by transforming by 50% in height).
For the background you just create your tiles with a side view instead using top view.

If you have problems understanding perspective you should maybe practice a bit doodling boxes from different angels/perspectives on paper first.